# Can someone correct my Json Code ?

Tags: json, manifest

I'm trying to do a Extension for Google Chrome and I receive the error : Unexpected Token

Thanks to everyone who will reply :D

http://i.gyazo.com/0e435fdc4d9432789834560a594480ab.png

This is my code :

```
}
    “manifest_version”: 2,
    “name”: “tf1“,
    “description”: “La chaine TF1 en direct“,
    “version”: “1.0″,
    “icons”: {
        “128″: “128.png”
    },
    “app”: {
        “urls”: [
            "http://www.tf1.fr/live/"
        ],
        “launch”: {
            “web_url”: “http: //www.tf1.fr/live/”
        }
    },
    “permissions”: [
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "notifications"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [edit] the title of your question to make it something meaningful and relevant to your question. A search for a problem here by a future reader is going to find no value in "Can someone correct my JSON code?" as a search result. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it should open with `{` instead of `}`.

Answer (score 2):

- Your JSON should begin with a `{`
- The quote characters seem like they were copied from somewhere. The JSON linter did not recognize it to be a valid quote character.

Fixing both:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "tf1",
    "description": "LachaineTF1endirect",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "128": "128.png"
    },
    "app": {
        "urls": [
            "http://www.tf1.fr/live/"
        ],
        "launch": {
            "web_url": "http: //www.tf1.fr/live/"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "notifications"
    ]
}
```

When you are not sure if your JSON is correctly formed, use this tool - [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). It tells you why your JSON is malformed.

Comment: Thanks Bro ! It's really nice from you

Answer (score 2):

JSON should be opened with `{` and closed with `}`.

I think your problem is in quotes symbols.

You have to use `"`, but you using `“`. I am not sure it is correct.

I assume, this will work:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "tf1",
    "description": "La chaine TF1 en direct",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "128": "128.png"
    },
    "app": {
        "urls": [
            "http://www.tf1.fr/live/"
        ],
        "launch": {
            "web_url": "http: //www.tf1.fr/live/"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "notifications"
    ]
}
```

You can try it here: http://jsonlint.com/